# How to order posts by custom field value in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, field

I wanna order posts by custom field value which now currently is posts view number. I tried with the following code

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$args = array(
        'post_type'  => 'product',
        'term'  => $queried_object->slug,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'product_views_count',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                'order' => DESC,
            )
        ),
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'terms' => array(
                    $queried_object->term_id
                )
            )
        )
    );
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

So with this am getting the current category posts but still it did not sort the posts by **product_views_count** custom field value.

Any idea what is wrong here?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have just misplaced the `orderby` argument. It goes in the top level. You also need to add a `meta_key` argument there too so it knows what to be ordering by.

I just slightly modified the code from your question to what you need. It's untested but should work just fine.

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$args = array(
        'post_type'     => 'product',
        'term'          => $queried_object->slug,
        'orderby'       => 'meta_value_num',
        'order'         => DESC,
        'meta_key'      => 'product_views_count',
        'meta_query'    => array(
            array(
                'key'       => 'product_views_count'
            )
        ),
        'tax_query'     => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'product_cat',
                'terms'     => array(
                    $queried_object->term_id
                )
            )
        )
    );
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @William Patton but i tested and still no luck. I see them in wrong order.

Comment: OK then I have an idea what it might be. Could you check that the posts that get shown contain a value for `products_views_count`. I've stumbled across an issue before ordering by number if no value was set.

Comment: Yes i checked and all contains a value. So i really don't know what is wrong here @William Patton.

Comment: Hmmm, yeah this is a peculiar one because as far as I can tell it SHOULD work. Perhaps I have a syntax error here in the code :( Unfortunately I don't have access to a dev environment where I can test this at the moment to try figure it out. Hopefully someone else can come by and post a working answer soon - if not I'll be able to test this code later today and try see what's wrong with it.

Comment: Yeah seems something silly is happening. Am still wanna fix this. ANy ideas that will help is appreciated @William Patton. Thanks